# Apply a select for every element of a column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-update

I would like to update third with a select that uses column first

```
|first #|second #|third #|
|_______|________|_______|
|___1___|___1____|_null__|
|___5___|___2____|_null__|
|___3___|___6____|_null__|
|___2___|___4____|_null__|
```

In pseudo code:

```
for row in table:
    row.third = result_of_a_select(row.first)
```

**What is the equivalent on SQL?**

My wrong attempt:

```
update example_table
set third= 
        (
          SELECT MAX(CDARTI) FROM 
            (
                SELECT A.CDARTI
                FROM PGMR.UT_ART_CODALT T,
                     PGMR.MRP_ARCH_ARTICOLI A
                WHERE 
                      A.CDARTI = T.CDARTI AND
                      T.CDARTI = first
                UNION

                SELECT A.CDARTI
                FROM PGMR.UT_ART_CODALT T,
                     PGMR.MRP_ARCH_ARTICOLI A
                WHERE 
                      A.CDARTI = T.CDARTI_A AND
                      T.CDARTI = first

                UNION

                SELECT A.CDARTI
                FROM PGMR.UT_ART_CODALT T,
                     PGMR.MRP_ARCH_ARTICOLI A
                WHERE 
                      A.CDARTI = T.CDARTI AND
                      T.CDARTI_A = first
                UNION

                SELECT A.CDARTI      
                FROM PGMR.UT_ART_CODALT T,
                     PGMR.MRP_ARCH_ARTICOLI A
                WHERE 
                      A.CDARTI = T.CDARTI_A AND
                      T.CDARTI = (SELECT T2.CDARTI FROM PGMR.UT_ART_CODALT T2 WHERE T2.CDARTI_A = first)
            )
        );
commit;
```

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: If your subquery works the update should work two. Do you get an error?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oracle. The code works but the result is wrong because the subquery result is always the same: 'first' is always the same at every run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Works for me.*

```
update t1 set third = (select third from t2 where t2.first = t1.first);
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da53d/1) (switched to MySql DB since I can't make Oracle work in it, but tested against my local Oracle as well).

The problem is not in the approach, but in your query. To fix that, you'll need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

A simplified test case:

```
SQL> create table yourTable (first, second, third) as (
  2      select 1, 1, cast (null as number) from dual union all
  3      select 5, 2, cast (null as number) from dual union all
  4      select 3, 6, cast (null as number) from dual union all
  5      select 2, 4, cast (null as number) from dual
  6      );

Table created.

SQL> update yourTable t
  2  set third = (select t.first * 2 from dual);

4 rows updated.

SQL> select * from yourTable;

     FIRST     SECOND      THIRD
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          2
         5          2         10
         3          6          6
         2          4          4

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it a slightly more interesting/illustrative example I'm updating the `third` column with the value from a mapping table and have included duplicate values.

You can use `MERGE` and match on the pseudocolumn `ROWID`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( first, second, third ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, CAST( NULL AS NUMBER ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 6, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 4, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4, NULL FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_name_map ( first, value ) AS
SELECT 1, 9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 5 FROM DUAL;
```

**Update**:

```
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING      ( SELECT t.ROWID AS ri,
                    m.value
             FROM   table_name t
                    INNER JOIN table_name_map m
                    ON ( t.first = m.first )
           ) src
ON         ( src.ri = dst.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET third = src.value;
```

**Result**:

```
FIRST SECOND THIRD
----- ------ -----
    1      1     9
    5      2     5
    3      6     7
    2      4     8
    3      4     7
```